# Randomly Generating Connected Directed Acyclic Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

I'm looking for a way to generate random connected directed acyclic graphs, where I can specify the number of vertices that have no outgoing edges (leaf vertices).

Anyone ever seen such a thing, or know how to generate such graphs?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by random in this context?

Comment: Basically, I provide the number of vertices, number of edges, and number of leaf vertices, and edges will be assigned randomly among the vertices.